# NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays IONIC 4

Tags: angular, api, object, ionic4, ngfor

I am developing a project in ionic 4.
I want to show country List in **ion-select**

I want to open the list on the click of button.
When I try with static value it works perfectly.

I also tried to convert response in array by:
**this.countryList = Array.of(this.countryList);**

My response is an array. But still it gives me error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find a differ
>   supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only
>   supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

**Respons:**

> [{"id":"1","name":"All","flag_img":"https://codehub.biz/knowledgeup/API/images/7515332518demo.jpg"},{"id":"2","name":"India","flag_img":"https://codehub.biz/knowledgeup/API/images/7617116068bg.png"},{"id":"3","name":"USA","flag_img":"https://codehub.biz/knowledgeup/API/images/4413910583ON40S50.jpg"}]

**authService.ts**

```
getData(type) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let data: Observable<any> = this.http.get(baseURL + type);
      data.subscribe(response => {
        // console.log("Auth GET Response : " , response);
        resolve(response);
      }, err => {
        console.log("Error", err);
        reject(err);
      }, () => {
        console.log('completed');
      });

    });
  }
```

**tab1.html**

```
<ion-item [hidden]='hideList'>
    <ion-label>Choose Country</ion-label>
      <ion-select placeholder="Country" #countryList (ionChange)="chooseCountry()" [(ngModel)]="userCountry">
        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let item of countryList" value="{{item.id}}" >{{item.name}}</ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
  </ion-item>

<ion-buttons slot="primary">
  <ion-button (click)='displayCountry()'>
    <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="globe"></ion-icon>
  </ion-button>
</ion-buttons>
```

**tab1.ts**

```
public countryList: any;
  userCountry: any;
hideList = true;
  @ViewChild('countryList', { static: false }) countrySelectRef: IonSelect;

ngOnInit() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('userId')) {
      this.isLogin = true
      this.userId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userId'));
      this.userName = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userName'));
      this.userCountry = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userCountry'));
      if (this.userCountry == null || this.userCountry == "") {
        this.isCountry = false;
      } else {
        this.isCountry = true
      }
    } else {
      this.isLogin = false;
    }

    console.log("isLogin : " + this.isLogin);
  }

getCountries(){
    this.authService.getData("getcountries.php").then((result) => {
      this.countryList = result;
      // this.countryList = Array.of(this.countryList);

      console.log(this.countryList);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log("Error", err);
    });
  } 

displayCountry() {
    this.countrySelectRef.open();
 }

chooseCountry(){
    console.log(this.userCountry);
    localStorage.setItem('userCountry', JSON.stringify(this.userCountry));
  }
```

Comment: Its simple declaration issue. You have declared countryList: any instead of countryList: any[];

Comment: I tried but the same error occurs. @AnoopRajasekharaWarrier

Comment: Please share a Stackblitz example.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to try out the async pipe in the template for this purpose. To achive this functinality you have to convert the countrylist to a ReplaySubject. Also If you are expecting an array as a response it is better the variable is also an array. If need any documentation here is the whole documentation for RxJs https://www.learnrxjs.io/
To get started with RxJs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs

**In html**

```
<ion-select-option *ngFor="let item of countryList|async">{{item.name}}</ion-select-option>
```

*In ts*

```
public countryList: ReplaySubject<any[]>=new ReplaySubject()

getCountries(){
   this.authService.getData("getcountries.php").then((result) => {
      this.countryList.next(result);
      console.log(this.countryList);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log("Error", err);
    })
}
```